# Unity Not accepting TCP connection, possibly refusing connection

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, unity-game-engine

I've been stuck with this for too long.

My script isn't allowing any TCP connections to come through from my device that is emitting them. I have tested my emitting device with Socket Test and they do work and transmit as I need. However, Unity is not accepting my signal and I don't know why.

Could someone please look over my script and see if they can work out the reason why? I've omitted  most of the debug lines.

```
   public class TCP : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    string ip_address  = "192.168.0.87";
    int port = 54321;
    public GameObject GText;

    Thread listen_thread;
    TcpListener tcp_listener;
    Thread clientThread;

    volatile bool should_stop;

    public void CloseSocket(TcpListener Client)
    {           
        //Client.Close();

    }


    public void Start()
    {          
    IPAddress ip_addy = IPAddress.Parse(ip_address);

    tcp_listener = new TcpListener(ip_addy, 22);
    tcp_listener.Start();

    StartAccept();

    }
    private void StartAccept()
    {
    tcp_listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, tcp_listener);
    GText.GetComponent<GUIText>().text =("Listening Again");
        Debug.Log("listeneing again");
    }
    private void HandleAsyncConnection(IAsyncResult res)
    {
            Debug.Log("handle async");
     byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
     string data;

    StartAccept(); //listen for new connections again
    TcpClient client = tcp_listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(res);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    //proceed

    int i;

    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
    i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                while (i != 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.ToUpper();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    // Send back a response.
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);

                    i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                }
    GText.GetComponent<GUIText>().text =("Second Operation");
    //CloseSocket(tcp_listener);

    }   
        void RequestStop()
    {
        should_stop = true;
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    /**
    void Start () 
    {
        try{
        IPAddress ip_addy = IPAddress.Parse(ip_address);
        tcp_listener = new TcpListener(ip_addy, port);
        listen_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        listen_thread.Start();  

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            GText.GetComponent<GUIText>().text =(e.ToString()); 
        }

    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this.tcp_listener.Start();

        while(true) 
        {
            //blocks until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = this.tcp_listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            this.tcp_listener.Stop();               

            client.Close();

        }

        this.tcp_listener.Stop();




    }

    */
    private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcp_client = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream client_stream = tcp_client.GetStream();


        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytes_read;

        while(true)
        {
            bytes_read = 0;

            try
            {
                //blocks until a client sends a message
                bytes_read = client_stream.Read(message, 0, 4096);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              //a socket error has occured
              GText.GetComponent<GUIText>().text =(e.Message);
                    Debug.Log(e.Message);
              break;
            }

            if(bytes_read == 0)
            {
                //client has disconnected
                break;
            }

            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        }
        try
        {
            clientThread.Abort();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            GText.GetComponent<GUIText>().text =(e.Message);
            Debug.Log(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Ive tried connecting to my unity app with socket test as well and I get an error saying the connection was refused. Can anyone see where in this code that happening?

Comment: I haven't checked your code, but if you're using the free version of Unity iOS or Unity Android, then Socket support is intentionally disabled (to get you to buy the pro version). http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses

Comment: @Calvin The data there explicitly shows .NET sockets to come with both the free and pro versions, doesn't it?

Comment: @Bart I'm seeing a checkmark missing for .NET Socket Support for the free versions of iOS, Android and Windows Store.

Comment: Ah @Calvin, you're right. I defaults to the Unity view for me. And I notice now the OP is talking about a "device". So you might well be correct there.